# How to add data from custom list view from sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

In android application i have a custom listview and sqlite database.
I want to display the database table value to custom listview.Please any one help me some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a website that might help

[SimpleCursorAdapters and ListViews](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something along the lines of this

```
          String[] fields = new String[] {Database.NAME};
    SimpleCursorAdapter  mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.names_listview,null,fields,
              new int[] {R.id.bListTextView});
      setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```